# 'Continue' and 'Retry' buttons location in action div

Tags: user-behavior, buttons, web, process, prompt

Regarding a Web console:

I have a process that stops from time to time when it has warnings and fails.
I'm allowing the user to retry or continue after taking care about the warnings and fails.

Retry - the process will retry the operations on the failed\warning entities
Continue - the process will ignore the failed\warnings entities and continue to the next phase

the 'Retry' and 'Continue' buttons are part of new div displayed\showing up in an end of running step.

What order should the buttons be placed?
"Retry , Continue" or "Continue , Retry"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be in the following sequence:

1. Retry
2. Continue

Reason: Retrying ensures that the user tries again to see if the Warning is now resolved and go ahead with a successful compilation. Hence, this is the recommended action to be first.

Continue ignores the warnings and can be used on the second go if the Retry option doesn't work. However, the recommendation will be always to retry.

Also, you could rename Continue to **Ignore** to make more sense.

[image: prompt]

Comment: Changing the label to 'ignore' or 'ignore the warning' is a good idea i think. However, I think you put too much emphasis on the order of the buttons. Mac users will expect the reverse order.
(windows: http://img.usabilitypost.com/0808/windows_save.png) (mac: http://www.macsinlaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/document-save-dialog1.jpg)

Comment: It needs to be in the order I have mentioned. This was not exclusive to Windows but as a good UX principle overall. The screenshot attached is only to give an example to support my point on the order. The order must be Retry and Ignore because Retrying is what needs to be done first, before ignoring. Please consider that the question hasn't mentioned Mac.

Comment: I did consider that and I only used Mac as an example. The question didn't mention Windows either. It mentions a web console, so you don't know what operating system the user is using. It could be anything from Windows to Linux. Maybe even a mobile operating system or the exotic OS2. Could you point to research that back-ups your claim?

Answer (score 3):

This can be compared to the OK-Cancel situation Nielsen/Norman group described in an article: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/ok-cancel-or-cancel-ok/

Spoiler: there is no right or wrong.

There are, however, a few things to keep in mind. First of all, make sure your choice is consistent. So if there are more situations like this, always put the confirmation button (in your case continue). If you're working on a desktop app, the OS can be the guideline for the order the buttons need to be in. If you're working on a web-app, this isn't as straightforward as on desktop and a look at the statistics can help you out. Are most users using a windows machine, then it's wise to put the OK-button first.

You can also use focus-state to guide to the attention of the user to the OK/Continue button. But unfortunately, this is also uncommon on the web. To solve this, you could design an alternate style for the button that stands out a more. Also, try to be descriptive in your labeling, just as you did with continue (instead of OK or confirm)